# How to find all imports placed in the code?

Tags: python

Our project contains a lot of import statements inside class/function. That was the way to overcome cycle import issue at the moment. And for now we want to research and fix design issue behind it.

For that purposes I want to find all that places with imports in code.

1. I have tried to search on "import" in Pycharm IDE and see imports not on the top of the file, but that does not show all this statements.
2. Then I tried to use pep8, to find all E402 error(Module level import not at top of file), but that does not show all in function impots, that are most interesting

So my question is, how to find all that import that placed in code not in the file header?

Comment: If you use some code quality tool like Flake8, maybe there are some plugins that could check for local imports (and raise a warning for instance)?

Comment: You can try to quickly make your own search tool using python / ReGex ... 
Otherwise you can create your own [librairy importer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

Comment: since the statements you're looking for are inside functions or methods, they will be preceded by at least one space.  So just do a regex search in your ide for `" +.*import"`.  (or with e.g. grep: `grep -E -C 3 -n '^ +.*import' **.py`)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pipreqs`](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/).

Running pipreqs with the default arguments will generate a `requirements.txt` for you.

```sh
$ pipreqs /home/project/location
Successfully saved requirements file in /home/project/location/requirements.txt
```

Comment: There stated that the import statements with its localtionsare looking for, not the requirements file

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Can you clarify please?